# Cannot create more than 20 webjobs (all are triggered)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I've been trying to find out why this is happening but basically we have 20 webjob workers that are triggered, and whenever we try to add more the creation fails through azure portal.

Previously we added all of them through the portal. The new ones are almost the same as the existing (we have 15 that are called queueWorker1 - 15), when trying to add more it always fails. Note we are creating a zip from visual studio and uploading it to portal

Is there a limit to how many webjobs can be added to one app service?

Can't seem to find any documentation or discussion about this

Comment: Would you mind accept my answer for others to refer if it helps?

Comment: According to the existing document description, `Doris's answer` is correct. If there is any problem with your webapp, it is recommended to raise a support ticket on the portal and let MSFT give you a specific analysis based on the log.

Comment: And you asked 6 questions, just mark your own answer, don’t you think it’s bad? Assuming you will ask questions later, even if others know they will not be willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

We can learn from the official document: [App Service Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

> There's no predefined limit on the number of WebJobs that can run in an App
> Service instance. There are practical limits that depend on what the
> application code is trying to do.

It might be other services' limits your process is accessing, which would be more complex. You could think about what services you are using and check if it has any limits on Azure.